# Is there a comprehensive list of special macros in Julia?

Tags: macros, julia

http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming/ discusses macros in Julia, which usually start with `@`, but also lists two special macros, `text_str`, and `cmd`, which handle `text"string"` and `` `shell command` ``, respectively. Is there a comprehensive list of these special macros supported by Julia? Is it possible to define your own?

Answer (score 6):

So all the *macros*, including string literal macros, are in [`exports.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/exports.jl).

If you are asking about these special syntax transformations in general like string literal macros, I don't think thats a question thats easily answerable: there are multiple arbitrary syntax translations like that that you can't do in user code (without using an `@` to denote you are transforming syntax with a macro). Most Julia macro-or-function-looking things aren't magic, but string literals, `ccall`, and maybe even things like `A'c` and the like would qualify.

Comment: I'm not sure we had tab-completion enabled when this was originally answered, but now it's even easier than looking at the source.  Just type `@<tab><tab>` and the entire list of exported macros will be printed out.

Answer (score 3):

The most sure-to-be-up-to-date way to find out is to enter the folder `base` and say `grep @ exports.jl`. If you're not on a Unix-like platform, then opening that file and looking at the `# Macros` section will also work.

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed possible to make your own; in fact every macro of the form

```
macro x_str(...)
end
```

is a String macro. Since 0.6, command macros are also supported by

```
macro x_cmd(...)
end
```